# Google language translate plugin not working properly (drop down change event)

Tags: javascript, onchange, google-translate

I have integrated google translate plugin in my website. After that I seen some unusual behavior in language selection drop down menu. Please note the following steps to reproduce issue:

1. Select language from drop down (except English) -it's working fine
2. Select English from drop down - it's working fine
3. Again Select language from drop down (except English) - This change
   event not convert page to selected language.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in Advance !!!

```
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<p>Hello everybody!</p>
<p>Translate this page:</p>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {pageLanguage: 'en',
         includedLanguages:'fr,it,pt,de,zh-CN,zh-TW,vi,es,en'},
        'google_translate_element'
    );      
}
</script>

<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. When i change the attribute

```
pageLanguage: 'en',
```

to

```
pageLanguage: 'es',
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing **pageLanguage: 'en'**  to **pageLanguage: 'es'** resolved my issue.